# How to capture OOO (out of office) emails using inbound parsing?

Tags: java, email, sendgrid, mailgun

My application sends emails to a list of contacts and I would like to capture the OOO (out-of-office) emails to automatically detect who is on vacations and (hopefully) discover, based on the message, when he/she is coming back. I'm trying to use the inbound parsing feature from Sendgrid and Mailgun to do that.

Both have the same behavior: they work fine when I manually send an email but they ignore the auto-response OOO messages for some reason. Does anyone have a clue of what is happening?

In both cases, I'm using the java library. Here are the code snippets:

Mailgun:

```
@Test
public void shouldSendEmailUsingMailgun() throws Exception {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
            .domain("<my_domain>")
            .apiKey("<my_api_key>")
            .from("<from>", "no-reply@subdomain.domain.com");

    Mail.using(configuration)
            .to("john@subdomain.domain.com")
            .subject("Mailgun testing OOO with reply-to")
            .text("Hello, from Mailgun")
            .replyTo("ooo@smartcanvas.com")
            .build()
            .send();

}
```

Sendgrid

```
    Email from = new Email("no-reply@subdomain.domain.com");
    String subject = "This is a test announcement from ooo detection";
    Email to = new Email("<recipient>");
    Content content = new Content("text/plain", "Hello, Email!");
    Mail mail = new Mail(from, subject, to, content);
    Email replyTo = new Email("no-reply@subdomain.domain.com");
    mail.setReplyTo(replyTo);


    SendGrid sg = new SendGrid("<api_key>");
    Request request = new Request();

    try {
        request.method = Method.POST;
        request.endpoint = "mail/send";
        request.body = mail.build();
        Response response = sg.api(request);
        System.out.println(response.statusCode);
        System.out.println(response.body);
        System.out.println(response.headers);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at a more full-featured inbound parser, such as [Mailparser.io](https://mailparser.io/) 
I'm not familiar with Mailgun's implementation, but SendGrid's Parse implementation is very basic. It should be sending the OOO responses to your endpoint, assuming it's configured properly, but it has no logic to parse the body, so you'd have to be doing that yourself.